# Guidance on Angular 1.2 and Angular 2 coexistence and incremental upgrade

Tags: angularjs, migration, angular

The existing code base in Angular 1.2 is huge with many custom directives, so I thought I will ask some experts before attempting.

I have studied the angular doc and am happy to see provision for an incremental upgrade using UpgradeAdapter. However, I am not clear the minimum version of Angular 1.x for the coexistence to work.

Specifically, can Angular 1.2 code co exist with  Angular 2 in the same application such that I can incrementally upgrade it to Angular 2?

Do I have to upgrade Angular 1.2 to 1.4 first (for ng-router) and then try the co existence and incremental upgrade strategy?

I tried searching for a definitive answer on this and could not locate one.

Answer (score 0):

Not a definite answer, but the source throws an error when not finding angular `1.x` : https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/upgrade/src/angular_js.ts#L128

One of their first recommandation in the upgrade guide is the use of components, available in angular `1.5` though.